# Flexbox alignment is not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container of items with the following style:

```css
.container-ok {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.container-error {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.item {
    width: 3rem;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-ok">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>

<div class="container-error">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

I'm expecting that all the items in the container are rendered in one column and are on the right side, but it's not working. When I remove `flex-direction`, it works but I have as example 3 items and they are in a row (3 columns) not one column. If I remove `justify-content` and replace it with `align-items`, it works. But `align-items` is for vertical alignment.

What am I doing wrong?

thank you

Comment: `align-items` is for alignment along the cross-axis (vertical in case of `row` direction) and `justify-content` for alignment along the flex-axis (horizontal for `row` direction) - for `column` direction it is the other way around... did not understand your question

Comment: "for column direction it is the other way around" that is the point which answers my question. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you want to achieve [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBpgoV) result

HTML

```
<div class="container-ok">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>

<div class="container-error">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-ok {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.container-error {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.item {
  width: 3rem;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

Also there is a nice [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to flexbox, maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Justify content declaration works because it defines the alignment along the main axis. Instead justify content not work because It defines the default behaviour for how flex items are laid out along the cross axis on the current line.  You can think of it as the justify-content version for the cross-axis (perpendicular to the main-axis).